# wpf c# public var of Application.Current.Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple windows in my wpf app.  Im finding that I have to constantly reference those windows inside various private functions like this:

```
var P1 = Application.Current.Windows
        .Cast<Window>()
        .FirstOrDefault(window => window is Player1Screen) as Player1Screen;
```

What is the easiest way to declare this once and then access it everywhere?

Comment: Your LINQ statement has a lot of redundancy... `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Player1Screen>().FirstOrDefault()` would be equally effective at less cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose it via a public static property in any class of your project (e.g. the `App` class):

```
public static Player1Screen Player1Screen
{
    get
    {
        return Application.Current.Windows
            .OfType<Player1Screen>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Note that I simplified the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something a little more reusable, you could create an extension method to find the window...

```
public static class AppEx
{
    public T FindWindowOfType<T>(this Application app) where T:Window
    {
        return app.Windows.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

so now:

```
Player1Screen win = Application.Current.FindWindowOfType<Player1Screen>();
```